# Extract uppercase words with optional numbers and underscore characters

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a Perl newbie need some Perl regex help. I want to extract **words** from a file which can contain only UPPERCASE characters and/OR numeric digits and the underscore characters (either at the beginning or end of the word or in the middle). The delimiter for the words can be whitespace or any other non-uppercase, non-digit, non-underscore.

3 examples:

```
abcd _PARAM123="dfd"; (I want to extract _PARAM123)
abcd PARAM2_:12; (I want to extract PARAM2_)
abcd PARA_M-1; (I want to extract PARA_M)
```

Comment: Do you need to support UTF8, codepoints above 127?

Comment: @Jerry - Am a hardware engineer and am learning Perl to parse my logs etc. Am a newbie in that I haven't gotten beyond arrays, hashes and simple substitutions. I was googling online for "string extraction" and wasn't able to make much progress and found regex quite puzzling (i tried many things which might sound too stupid and numerous to be listed); so i wanted some help to fix my problem quickly and learn at my own pace; ergo the question. Thanks

Comment: Okay, sure. And could you provide some more samples? What about `abcd 1PARAM_T=3` Would you like to extract `1PARAM_T`? Or what if you have `abcd PARAM=PARAM2`?

Comment: @DavidO - I don't need to support UTF-8

Comment: @Jerry - second case too. any UC word containing underscore and numbers and sperated by anything else

Comment: @user2805732 Does that mean you need both `PARAM` and `PARAM2`?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, both PARAM and PARAM2

Comment: Okay, one last check, a **word** doesn't count as a word if there's only numbers (and/or underscores), right?

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
my @words = $str =~ /( [A-Z_] [0-9A-Z_]+ )/xg;
```

Comment: Jerry: Yes, I'm making that assumption because it seems like something the OP probably just forgot to mention.  I don't trust the spec, so I'm not going to go through writing an answer that includes variations to solve every possible interpretation of the question. :)  But I'll retract my hint, since I'm just guessing at the real spec.

Comment: @DavidO I know, just pointing out. I think that questions like that shouldn't be answered until OP's entirely clear.

Comment: We still don't even know what he considers upper case: Does he need to support code points above 127?

Comment: Ok, the "other regex": `m/([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)/g`, because identifiers almost always must start with alpha or underscore.

Comment: Thanks guys! The pattern even extracts "underscore" between lower case characters e.g. "abcd_param" returns "_", but i can search a replace these things. Can someone please tell me the difference between the '+ ' sign and the '*' sign before the ')'

Comment: @user2805732 + matches 1 or more times, and * matches 0 or more times

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't replied to my last query, I'm going to assume that a word doesn't count as a word if there's only numbers (and/or underscores), for example `12` and `1_2` are not considered as words.

In that case, I suggest this regex:

```
(?=[0-9_]*[A-Z])\b[A-Z0-9_]+\b
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dO6uQ9)

`(?=[A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z])` is a positive lookahead and makes sure that there's at least one uppercase character in the regex. If you consider `1_2` as a word, use `(?=[A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z_])` instead.

`\b` is a word boundary and is what ensures there's no lowercase characters attached to the word you're looking for.

`[A-Z0-9_]` is a character class and will match any character within the range of `A-Z` (uppercase letters), `0-9` (digits) and an underscore.

`+` means that the previous group or character can occur 1 or more times.