# How to extract upper case words within a long string using perl

Tags: string, perl, case-sensitive

I am trying to find a way to extract only upper case words (at least three consecutive upper characters, plus numbers) from quite a long string using perl.

Example:

```
"Hello world, thank GOD it's Friday, I can watch EPISODE4"
```

Output:

```
"GOD EPISODE4"
```

For some reason I cannot come up with a sensible way to do this, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200886/extract-uppercase-words-with-optional-numbers-and-underscore-characters ?

Comment: To also ask for detecting numbers and subtracting one makes it a bit harder...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I had some typo in the number, I only wanted the query to extract the number not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use character classes:

```
my @matches = ( $string =~ /\b[[:upper:]|[:digit:]]{3,}+\b/g );
say join " - ", @matches;
```

(You stated uppercase characters *and* numbers. You didn't specify where the number would be. You also didn't say whether or not I need to do something with the number.

Edit your question to include other requirements).

Comment: Thanks, though the 'say' command did not work for me, maybe I have an old version of Perl.

Comment: You have to add `use feature qw(say);` to the top of your program, and have a version of Perl newer than 5.10 (which is about seven years old).

Answer (score 0):

This will get you any upper case words that are over 3 characters and which may or may not have numbers at the end:

```
my $str = "Hello world, thank GOD its Friday, I can watch EPISODE4"; 
my @matches = ($str =~ /\b([A-Z]{3,}+[0-9]*)\b/g);
```

You can modify it to look for upper case characters after the numbers:

```
my @matches = ($str =~ /\b([A-Z]{3,}+[0-9]*[A-Z]*)\b/g);
```