# Find runs of capitalized letters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file containing some fully capitalized words and some mixed-case words, and I want to extract the fully capitalized runs of words (contained in one line) – that is, things separated by `\b` and containing at least two capital letters and no lowercase letters. Everything is 7-bit.

So, for example, if a line is

```
The QUICK Brown fox JUMPs OV3R T4E LAZY DoG.
```

then I'd want to extract `QUICK` and `OV3R T4E LAZY`.

This is what I have so far:

```
while (<$fh>) { # file handle
    my @array = $_ =~ /\b[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\b/;
    push @bigarray, @array;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it than `[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*`?

Comment: consecutive capitals, or 2+ capitals anywhere in the word. e.g. `CApital` or `cApiTal`? consecutive is easy. 2+ anywhere, not so much.

Comment: @MarcB consecutive. But also including other `\w` characters, but no lowercase letters.

Comment: "other `\w` characters, but no lowercase letters" - so numbers and underscores?

Comment: See [How to extract upper case words within a long string using perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415808/176646)

Comment: Example matches / non matches would help

Comment: @dawg done: see revised question.

Comment: You wouldn't want to match the first `A` in `A QUICK Brown fox JUMPs OV3R T4E LAZY DoG.`? It is a fully-capitalized word. What about the `I` in `I think, therefore I am.`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want all word definition (construct `\w`) characters.
To find and allow at least two caps and no lower case, you're probably not going to
get around the fact that they have to be optionally surrounded by caps
and or digits or underscore.

Might as well just match what you need.

`\b[\d_]*[A-Z]+[\d_]*[A-Z]+[\d_]*\b`

Expanded:

```
 \b 
 [\d_]* 
 [A-Z]+ 
 [\d_]* 
 [A-Z]+ 
 [\d_]* 
 \b
```

*ah, results*

Input:

```
The QUICK Brown fox JUMPs OV3R T4E LAZY DoG.
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 4 , len 5 ) 
QUICK  
-----
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 26 , len 4 ) 
OV3R  
-----
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 31 , len 3 ) 
T4E  
-----
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 35 , len 4 ) 
LAZY
```

---

*update* - If you want to optionally match consecutive portions separated by whitespace,
this would work.

```
 # (?&two_caps)(?:\s+(?&two_caps))*(?(DEFINE)(?<two_caps>\b[\d_]*[A-Z]+[\d_]*[A-Z]+[\d_]*\b))

 (?&two_caps) 
 (?:
      \s+ (?&two_caps) 
 )*

 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<two_caps>
           \b 
           [\d_]* 
           [A-Z]+ 
           [\d_]* 
           [A-Z]+ 
           [\d_]* 
           \b 
      )
 )
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 4 , len 5 ) 
QUICK  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
---------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 26 , len 13 ) 
OV3R T4E LAZY  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL
```

Comment: +1 for you, because I *think* this accurately answers the question as it appeared until 49 seconds before you posted this. 49 seconds before you posted this, I corrected a mistake in the question, and this answer doesn't correctly answer the question any longer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a *run* of those matches, maybe use split with zero width assertions and then filter the results:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    for my $e (split (/(?<=\b)([A-Z0-9_ ]+)(?=\b)/)){
        $e =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
        print "$e\n" unless ($e =~/^$/ or $e =~ /.*[a-z]/);
    }
}

__DATA__
The QUICK Brown fox JUMPs OV3R T4E LAZY DoG.
```

Prints:

```
QUICK
OV3R T4E LAZY
```

So how does this work?

The `split` will separate out the parts the match your criteria from those that do not:

```
use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    print Dumper split (/(?<=\b)([A-Z0-9_ ]+)(?=\b)/); 
}
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = 'The';
$VAR2 = ' QUICK ';
$VAR3 = 'Brown';
$VAR4 = ' ';
$VAR5 = 'fox';
$VAR6 = ' ';
$VAR7 = 'JUMPs';
$VAR8 = ' OV3R T4E LAZY ';
$VAR9 = 'DoG.';
```

The loop then loops over that array, strips whitespace from each element, and tests for a lower case character or blank line.

Which leads to a single line to produce your array for each line:

```
grep { $_ =~ /(?=[A-Z]{2,})^[^a-z]+$/ } map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $_} split (/(?<=\b)([A-Z0-9_ ]+)(?=\b)/);
```

Comment: This is interesting, I've benched a lot of stuff using Perl. Used a lot of split and further looping to accomplish what a single regex would do. I think it's just paranoia of regex myself. Too much talk about regex is the boogyman.. anyway, dunno.

Comment: I love regex's . Not the boogyman at all. It just made more sense to me in this case...

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?=\S*[A-Z]\S*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/24